# Get fields of lookup records in a custom button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I'm trying to check if some fields on the lookup records are filled in(not null).

I have a custom lookup field on *Lead* to *Account*, let's call it `Some_Account__c`. I also have a custom button on *Lead* and when a user clicks on it I want to make a check if all required fields are filled in(**note**: by required I mean that they are only required at the moment of clicking the button, so they can possibly be empty).

Here's the code snippet of that button:

```
if ({!OR( ISNULL( Lead.Some_Account__r.My_Custom_Field_1__c ) ,ISNULL( Lead.Some_Account__r.My_Custom_Field_2__c ))}) {
    alert('please fill in the required fields');
}
```

So basically I check if any of those fields is empty, and if at least one of them is, I want to show an alert.

However, I get the following error:

> Error: Field Lead.Some_Account__r.My_Custom_Field_1__c does not exist. Check spelling.

So the question is: can I somehow access the fields of the lookup records with JavaScript custom button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationship is not available in your javascript so there are 2 solution of this issue.

1. Create a formula field on Lead object and then test that value inside javascript (IF(!Lead.YOURFORMULAFIELDFROMACCOUNT))
2. Use Javascript api if you are familiar with to get Account fields

   var contactCheck = sforce.connection.query("SELECT MY_CUSTOM_FIELD__C FROM           ACCOUNT WHERE ID = '{!LEAD.Some_Account__c}' limit 1");

   records = contactCheck.getArray("records");

   if(records[0].MY_CUSTOM_FIELD__c=='')

   alert('Field is empty');